# How do I reassign data in R from words to binary 1's and 0's?

Tags: r

Right now I have a column of data that is "blue" or "green" and I want it to display a 1 for "blue" and 0 for "green."  Any help?

Comment: I am surprised nobody suggested you use a logical vector, which makes a lot more sense: `is_blue <- x == "blue"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluations of logical statements can be converted to binary values.

```
x = c("blue", "green", "blue")
as.integer(x == "blue")
```

Comment: this worked, but I had to include the column name in the c(  )  otherwise it only gave binary for the first 3 values I put in parenthesis.  Thanks a lot for the help, getting hung up on something so small is frustrating!

Answer (score 3):

This is a safer approach than several of the others given so far, because it won't silently miscode a value other than `"blue"` or `"green"` that happens to occur in your input vector `x`:

```
x <- c("blue", "green", "blue", "blue", "red")
match(x, c("green", "blue")) - 1
# [1]  1  0  1  1 NA
```

Alternatively (and even easier to arbitrarily extend), use the following (h.t. thelatemail):

```
val <- setNames(c(0,1,10), c("green", "blue", "red"))
x <- c("blue", "green", "blue", "blue", "red", "orange")
val[x]
# blue green  blue  blue   red  <NA> 
#    1     0     1     1    10    NA
```

Comment: You could also use indexing to achieve a similar outcome: `vals <- setNames(c(1,0),c("blue","green")); vals[x];`

Comment: @thelatemail -- Very nice. That's even better.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that (there are several)

```
vec <-rep(c("blue","green"),3)
ifelse(vec=="blue",1,0)
#[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it

```
vec[vec=="blue"] <-1
vec[vec=="green"] <-0
as.numeric(vec)
#[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0
```